# issue with storing a return promise result into a variable

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I'm having trouble understanding why my values that I've retrieve from the API, is not being stored in this.schedule. When I console.log my result from my call, I see the returned Promise. My assumption is that when I use .then, I am storing the value into the variable schedule. What am I overlooking?

```
var getData = function(url, teamId) {
  var object = {
    "schedule": [],
    "record": null,
    "nextSixGames": [],
    "url": url
  };

  this.url = url
  var schedule = utils.teamSchedule(url, teamId).then(function(result) {
    return result
  });

  this.schedule = schedule;

  return object;
}

getData(URL, teamID)
console.log(getData(URL, teamID))
```

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous function. Promises are asynchronous.

Comment: Also `this` is not what you think it is. `this.schedule` and `object.schedule` are two different properties

Comment: I'm still confused, I looked at other questions on stack overflow, but they all use console.logs to verify their answer. No where do they use "resolve()", I am guessing that is how I go about storing the values I want into a variable right? 
   ` var schedule = utils.teamSchedule(url, teamId).then(function(result) {
    return Promise.resolve(result)
  });`

I've tried resolving, but it doesn't seem to work, as it seems it is still async. Where am I going wrong.